# Xuggler on Android

Tags: android, xuggler

I am trying to use Xuggler on Android to convert WAV files to M4A.

I have used the xuggle-xuggler-noarch-5.4.jar in my java build path

and copied the libxuggler.so file out of xuggle-xuggler-arch-i686-pc-linux-gnu.jar to my libs folder within my android application.

in my main activity i have a static initialiser that attempts to System.loadlibrary("libxuggler")

however i just get these set of info and error messages

```
I/dalvikvm(27614): Could not find method com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.makeReader, referenced from method com.example.quality.MainActivity.convertToMP3
W/dalvikvm(27614): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3376: Lcom/xuggle/mediatool/ToolFactory;.makeReader (Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/xuggle/mediatool/IMediaReader;
W/dalvikvm(27614): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/quality/MainActivity$6; (485)
W/dalvikvm(27614): Link of class 'Lcom/example/quality/MainActivity$6;' failed
W/dalvikvm(27614): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/example/quality/MainActivity;
W/dalvikvm(27614): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/example/quality/MainActivity;)
W/dalvikvm(27614): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40acf228)
```

My System.loadlibrary called failed with

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libxuggle: findLibrary returned null
```

is it possible to use Xuggler on Android

What have i done wrong?

What havent i done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an explanation on xuggler-users group from Art Clarke :

> I have not attempted to port xuggler to android, but if someone is interested all jvm related code is in the 'ferry' module.  Memory mgmt is particularly complicated and hard, but in theory a port would be possible.